# Can a Silverlight 4 out-of-browser app run other applications?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I read in a few places it can run "desktop programs such as Office" but I haven't seen any other details or concrete confirmation of this. Anyone know? If so, how can it be done if SL4 OoB apps only have read/write access to User Special Folders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the WScript.Shell COM object you can do a lot including launching an arbitrary process. There is some info about it here:

http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Silverlight-4-elevated-permissions.aspx

Comment: That's interesting. Unfortunately, that would only work on computers running Windows.

Comment: Yes hopefully there will be some sort of Apple native integration, ideally by the time Silverlight 4 ships. Scott Guthrie in a Q&A session said it's something they're researching.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I have seen, Silverlight 4 can only interact with other applications through COM.  Office uses COM and thus can be manipulated by SL4.